# While solving some problems of time complexity, got stuck in the following code fragment

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

What will be the time complexity of the following code?

```
    for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
     for(j=0;j<=log i;j++)
      print("hello world");
```

Comment: And I think complexity would be O(n) = n.log(log n)

Comment: https://www.daniweb.com/programming/computer-science/threads/13488/time-complexity-of-algorithm here is an old (but still good) reference on how to calculate time complexity that might answer your question

Comment: @user9335240 I disagree - it's on-topic here because it's a question about an algorithm. A bigger problem is that the OP doesn't show their prior attempt or research.

Comment: [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11032015)

Answer (score 2):

Summing up the number of times the inner loop is iterating, we get,

```
log1 + log2 + log3 + log4 + ... + logN 
= log(N!)
```

And according to [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), `log(N!) = O(N x log(N))`
So the time complexity is `O(NlogN)`